RecyclerviewAdapter using firebase doesn't sort correctly for more than 5 items
I'm experiencing an issue with my RecyclerView adapter. When I have fewer than 5 items in my Firebase database, the adapter works perfectly, and tapping an item displays the correct details. However, when I add more items (beyond 5), the adapter starts behaving erratically. Tapping an item displays the details of a different item, not the one I tapped. I suspect the issue lies within my adapter implementation. Can anyone help me identify the problem and suggest a solution?
The Recyclerview adapter is not working as intended here is it
package com.app.rednet.myspaceapp.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.app.rednet.myspaceapp.Activity.DetailActivity;
import com.app.rednet.myspaceapp.Domain.ItemDomain;
import com.app.rednet.myspaceapp.databinding.ViewholderRecommendedBinding;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecommendedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecommendedAdapter.Viewholder> {
    private final ArrayList<ItemDomain> items;
    private Context context;
    ViewholderRecommendedBinding binding;

    public RecommendedAdapter(ArrayList<ItemDomain> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecommendedAdapter.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        binding=ViewholderRecommendedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()),viewGroup,false);
        context=viewGroup.getContext();
        return new Viewholder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecommendedAdapter.Viewholder viewholder, int i) {
        binding.titleTxt.setText(items.get(i).getTitle());
        binding.priceTxt.setText("MWK"+items.get(i).getPrice());
        binding.addressTxt.setText(items.get(i).getAddress());
        binding.scoreTxt.setText(""+items.get(i).getScore());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(items.get(i).getPic())
                .into(binding.pic);
        viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = viewholder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    ItemDomain item = items.get(position);
                    intent.putExtra("object", item);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Viewholder(ViewholderRecommendedBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
        }
    }
}



What do you mean by "not the one I tapped"? Which one is displayed?

I mean when I click item on position one ,I get details of item on position 6 or other position not exactly one I tapped

Have you tried Tommly's solution? Does it work for you?

Yes I tried but It didn't work

What exactly didn't work? Do you have the same behavior?

Yaa same behavior

If you try to log the value of item inside your adapter are you getting the right item?

He should share a gist with his code so that we can have a look

add this in your onBindViewHolder
ItemDomain itemDomain = items.get(position);

then use itemDomain to get position of the item
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("object", itemDomain);
    context.startActivity(intent);

make sure itemDomain implements Parcelable or Serializable
public class Item implements Parcelable {

//items
//getter/setters
//constructor

// Parcelable implementation
protected Item(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    price = in.readDouble();
    address = in.readString();
    score = in.readInt();
}
 public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
        @Override
        public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Item(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Item[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeDouble(price);
    parcel.writeString(address);
    parcel.writeInt(score);
}
}


Thank you for your suggestions...I tried but it didn't work still the same..what else I have to check?

what is the new error + share a gist with your code so I can have a deeper look

public class ItemDomain implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private String pic;
    private int price;



    public ItemDomain() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(String pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}

This is my data class

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
